# Most complex locked phone ever, needs a genius to solve

Tags: lock-screens, recovery-mode, usb-debugging

Is there any hope. I feel I have exhausted all the options I have any knowledge of. I’ll explain the situation and methods i have tried.

I broke the screen on my galaxy s2 causing the touch screen to not respond and then eventually the screen to go black.

The phone got replaced and sat in a box until one days I felt the need to find out what I had left on the old phone, photos, information just out of pure curiosity.

I was able to turn the phone on and although I couldn't see anything I could hear texts coming through, the phone was buzzing etc. Anyway couldn’t see what was going on. So I borrowed my girlfriends galaxy s2 which she no longer uses and used the screen off that to use as the screen for mine via the ribbon cable. Watched a youtube video and it was all fine, booted up okay until I realised the phone was LOCKED! locked with a pin, of x amount of digits long.

I tried every possible combination I have every used, never used, I am never guessing the thing. I can’t remember if it is my usual 4 numbered pin or whether it is numbers that would spell a word.

Tried plugging into a computer but of course it wont pick it up until the correct password is entered.

The gmail unlock option, the phone has been out of use for over a year, possibly 2. It no longer shows up on account and I have no signal on the phone either. (I did put the sim back in, just realising now if i removed an aerial or something when fitting the new screen). I don’t have signal at all. there is no forgot password option.

Tried downloading kies to my mac and doing it via a usb but ran into the same problem as before.

downloaded software onto an sd card but I cannot get the device to boot into recovery mode, I think it may be because the volume buttons are not working. I am trying a method of battery out and charge the phone, heard someone say that this can force a htc into recovery mode so i thought it is at least worth a try.

I will not be defeated. I DO NOT WANT TO DO A FACTORY RESET. I will keep trying every possible option until I get a solution. Turn on the phone and find that nothing on there was worth the hassle.

I see a few ways out of this

1 bypass the lock screen via black magic and or disable it

2 somehow regain signal then use gmail account recovery, ( i don't know if a sim becomes redundant after a period of inactivity)]

3 somehow enable a pc/mac to pick it up

4 not sure about the usb otg method

Any help much appreciated

[image: photo of lock screen to determine android viersion]

Comment: Do you know what Android version was installed? Android 4.x (Jelly Bean, Ice Cream Sandwich, or the ***old*** Android 2.x Gingerbread? Post a screenshot of your lockscreen and we can determine for you. Also tell us the exact model number of the phone, so we can determine if it's bootloader unlocked or not.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting to recovery via ADB?

Comment: I'm not sure what software it is but I'll send a photo of my lock screen. Iv tried booting it into recovery mode or safe mode but this isn't working, I think it's down to tho volume buttons not working due to being in pieces. Has anyone got experience of using a USB keyboard to boot into recovery mode? Iv flashed software to the sd card for bypassing the lock screen or deleting the password but obviously I can't get to that point yet.

Comment: @Gavin you need to @ me next time so I know you responded! According to the picture you have Gingerbread installed! Which is good news, 2.3 has gaping security holes. If you pop in a SIM card and call that phone number, or use emergency call, you should be able to get to the homescreen via some magic key combos. [Look here](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection?lq=1) for answers.

Comment: @AaronGillion, thanks for that!! The phone was on 02, but I took my number across to EE. So when I have put back in the old 02 sim related to that old number it did not connect me to a cellular network. Could this also be because the sim had not been used in so long? (Not sure whether they expire or not). I am assuming if I get an active 02 sim this will automatically connect then I can try the methods mention regarding calling the handset. Once again, many thanks. I'll be sure to let you know how I get on. Will be 2+ weeks till I get the chance

Comment: @AaronGillion, Are you able to tell from that photo why I wasn't receiving a signal? Was it due to - The sim being expired/unused or when splitting the phone have I disconnected the antenna?

Comment: Not sure. Your phone might be carrier locked so that you can't use prepaid Sim cards? Maybe you can find another method from that link I gave you? Izzy's answer covers ***all*** the methods of getting in to an unlocked phone.