# Locked phone-google account info not working to unlock-can't use device manager

Tags: samsung, google-account, locked-out

My Samsung Galaxy is locked due to me letting my grandbabies draw incorrect pattern too many times. Screen on phone says"to unlock, sign in with your Google account".  I have tried this.  Phone remains locked.

As far as I can remember I only have 1 google account.  I have tried to find out if I have any other Google accounts...as far as I can tell, I don't.

I tried to use device manager to unlock.  My phone is on, but I utilize battery save settings...no internet, 4G, location settings unless I specifically go in and turn them on.

I've tried a few thing found on-line... calling my phone from another phone and trying to get in to unlock while on the call, using "null" password, using some random number password.

I've gone to 2 Sprint stores and they want to do a factory reset where I lose everything on my phone.  I've been trying to avoid doing factory reset due to pictures, texts, vm, contacts saved on my phone.

It's been over a week that I have not been able to access vm, texts, or make calls.  I can receive calls.
HELP PLEASE!!!!!
Thanks

Firelord...I'm not sure what model...behind the battery there is a code:SPH-D700...is that the model?  The phone is about 6 years old.

Izzy...I did not find anything that worked on the wiki.  I did not try the app mentioned as I was not clear if it required my phone to have internet or wireless enabled prior to it being locked.  There were a couple posts that were a bit over my head regarding rooting and programming code.
Thanks

Comment: Which particular Galaxy model is it? We need to know its codename.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, Susan! Please start at our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) and especially follow up to [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575) for our collected wisdom :)

Comment: Also, regarding a factory reset. If you had your device synced with your Google Account, all pictures, contacts, emails, etc. will be backed up there. Voicemail is handled by your carrier, so resetting the device will not affect it.