# Qmobile Forgotten Unlock Pattern

Tags: locked-out, pattern-lock

I've forgotten the unlock pattern for my Qmobile i7i and it does not provide me with the option to enter my email, backup pin, etc. Factory restore is not an option as there is important data on the device.

How can I bypass the pattern lock?

Comment: Please start with our [locked-out tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info), which we created with first-aid and useful links on exactly this topic. Especially follow up to [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35847/16575)

Comment: where it is asked already? Izzy ??

Comment: In the linked question. [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/35848/16575) lists up available methods to bypass pattern lock.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you can do is to make the backup of all the files which you can do so by copying all the files from the phone to your PC via USB connection.

The files you copied will include the contacts, media, system related file. Once you have copied all files then you can later copied back to your phone after phone reset.

Here is the link to reset your phone:

http://www.morenews.pk/2016/01/02/factory-reset-qmobile-noir-android-smartphone-forgotten-lock/

Another link:

http://www.phonerework.com/hard-reset-qmobile-noir-i7-to-unlock-pattern-lock/

Comment: not possible i'm connecting the phone via usb and when i clicked on import pic and videos and all options one by one nothing happens...when i click on open files to view then only empty folder opens...any other way to copy the data?

Comment: Did you install QMobile software which comes in CD in the box? try it out. Hopefully that will allow you to copy files.