# How to Bypass a pattern lockscreen on a oneplusone phone

Tags: password, pattern-lock

I have A one plus one phone and i forgot my password (pattern).
and i dont have a google recovery account and a recovery pin
and i need all my stuff from the phone.

what can i do to unlock it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection)

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded in removing the lock pattern on a rooted OnePlus One using the below.

On the OnePlus forums an employee [suggested](https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/forgot-unlock-pattern-help-to-bypass-it.179551/#post-7443771) this:

> You have to delete all your key files from system folder. Try this.
>   Connect you device with usb and run following command. If you are not able to do so, i am afraid. You need a full wipe.
>
> ```
> adb devices
> adb shell
> su
> cd /data/system
> rm *.key
> ```
>
> Even if shows lock screen after reboot, try a easy random pattern.

In my case that worked, besides the tiny detail that the `su` would spawn an approval prompt, which I of course couldn't confirm because of the pattern lock.

However, because the device was rooted (and you might be able to do this after the fact, that I don't know) I could boot it into recovery (holding Power + Volume Down), in my case TWRP. In there I could rename the 3 `*.key` files and pronto, after a reboot the pattern lock was gone.

As a side note, this is a demonstration that any screen lock is pretty useless from a security perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Try Hard Reset

1. Turn off the device (Not just the screen)
2. Hold <kbd>power</kbd> and <kbd>home</kbd> buttons
3. Then after the android logo appears use <kbd>volume</kbd> and <kbd>power</kbd>, to select "Factory data reset" (or similar words to do with resetting). Then your device will start from the beginning.

Hope this will work for you as it worked for me :D

Answer (score 0):

if you have custom recovery like TWRP, they allow mounting your filesystem in recovery mode to allow file transfers in recovery mode.Then all you have to do is

1. boot into recovery mode
2. mount required filesystems
3. Select Mount USB Storage
4. connect you phone to your PC

Assuming you have installed you device manufacturer's drivers your device should show up on your PC.