# Genymotion pattern forgotten

Tags: lock-screens, locked-out, genymotion

I am using genymotion to emulate Google Nexus 9.It so happens that I was not using this virtual machine for about a month so I have forgotten its pattern(yes it was protected by pattern lock). Now I need to use emulated Google Nexus 9 but it can't due to pattern lock. So how can I bypass or change pattern lock so I can again gain access to my device.

P.S.-I have seen [Can not unlock my Android device as have no internet connection?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35847/can-not-unlock-my-android-device-as-have-no-internet-connection) but for methods in this link I need to go to recovery mode but that can't be done in emulated phone(I think so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Genymotion comes with VirtualBox (if you haven't already installed it).
Open it up and you should see your emulator there with a preview of the screen.
The content is just a terminal with white text on a black background.
We can use this terminal to interact with the shell fairly easily, no authentication required.

Open the window (press the green `Show` button) and simply delete *all* `*.key` files in the `/data/system/` directory.
Luckily the terminal is already running as the root user and thus we can execute the command `rm /data/system/*.key`.
This deletes *all* encoded and hashed lock information and forces the system to remove any protection present (a feature of Android's KeyGuard to prevent full system lockouts).

Reboot the emulator (using the command `reboot`) and wait a few seconds.

To conclude: Don't try to protect an emulator, there is and there should never be any reason to store private data on a mainly volatile emulated system. These emulator are designed to help you create apps (which means sometimes wait a long time to finish the build) and a lock screen is more than just annoying to unlock every time you need to test a new version.