# Disable Pattern lock with usb debugging or Login to WiFI network

Tags: adb, locked-out

### Summary

I forgot the pattern lock on my new phone, it's an Acer Z630S running android 5.1. I managed to turn the WiFi on, but the only network my phone knows right now requires me to accept some conditions on a login page, however tapping the "Login to WiFi" notification asks for the pattern.

Fortunately I have USB debugging enabled, and my pc is a trusted device. Can I circumvent the lock screen is some way, or can I tap a button to log in to the WiFi network?

### I also found [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35848) but none of those methods worked, here's a list of what went wrong with each of them:

- Credentials stuff

My phone doesn't ask for them.

- Bypass screenlock using a special app

I don't have WiFi, so I can't download anything.

- Unlock via web

No WiFi, so isn't going to work.

- Disable Pattern Lock via ADB

As in one of the WiFi attempts: sqlite isn't installed, pulling doesn't work and mounting doesn't work either.

- Similar thing without ADB

My phone is not yet rooted.

- Phone hole stuff

I'm not in my home country and accepting calls costs a lot of money, so I can't really do that right now.

- Samsung users with Windows PC

It's an Acer device.

### Any other things?

I've tried to document everything as good as possible, but I'd happily answer any other questions you might have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method will only work if you have an sd-card slot on your device and it's rooted.

You mentioned that you can't download any apps to bypass screenlock as you don't have an internet connection. But what you can do is:

- Download any similar app on your PC (as an apk from the internet)
- Create a recovery-flashable zip out of it, ie, make an update.zip package from the apk and save it onto your sd-card (using a card reader or a different device)
- Insert the sd-card into your device boot it into recovery mode
- Install the package (update.zip) from recovery

The app should take care of the rest.

---

If your device isn't rooted or your device does't have an external card slot, follow [this link](http://visihow.com/How_to_unlock_an_android_locked_out_device_with_no_internet_connection) to learn how to factory reset your device from it's locked state, but it would wipe your device's data, so proceed cautiously.

Comment: My phone is not yet rooted. I tried it anyway using the build-in recovery with [this tutorial](https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-android-apps-recovery-zip/) with [this apk](http://m.downloadatoz.com/apps/net.thomascannon.screenlockbypass.fix,165617/download.html)  but the recovery simply said "Installation Aborted". I guess I'll have to factory reset my device unfortunately.