# how to unlock android device manager

Tags: applications, lock-screens

I forgot my Xiomi Redmi note 3 phone pattern lock so I locked it with android device manager but my mobile still shows the same after it. It doesn't show any box to type the new password to unlock it . Does someone know what would i try to do now?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it out on my device (running Android 7.1.2 if that matters). In [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) I clicked the `Lock` button. It asked me to enter a new password twice, a recovery message (optional) and a phone number (also optional).

It first showed that the new lock was successfully set. However, this message was quickly replaced with `Since Google has verified that a screen lock is already set, the password you entered won't be needed`. This second message disappeared pretty quickly so you may have missed it.

When I proceeded to unlock my phone, it displayed `Locked by Android Device Manager` on the screen. By pressing the `Back` button, I got back into the regular lock screen which now displayed `Device administrator locked device`. My previous lock method was still active, so I could unlock it as if nothing had changed. Therefore, I suspect that your phone's lock hasn't changed either, which means you'll need to find a different way of changing the lock. Please try the methods in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35848) and let us know which one worked for you (if any).