# How can I mirror broken Samsung S4 GT I9505 unlocked screen onto Laptop or TV?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-4, broken-screen

How can I project broken Samsung S4 GT I9505 unlocked screen onto Laptop or TV?

Fortunately with multiple trials the pattern worked out on BLACK display screen and phone got unlocked and I took Data Backup using Samsung Kies 3.2 version.

But the phone is sensitive to get locked automatically in 10 to 15 seconds. Somehow managed the phone in active without getting locked.

How can I permanently remove lock on BLACK Broken screen by any means of mirroring the phone UI on to TV or Laptop to get UI control and can remove the lock by going into the phone settings?

Please Help!

Comment: Why? What data do you still need?

Comment: I want to remove lock pattern from phone settings via PC control

Comment: Please take a look at the **[`broken-screen`](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info)** tag.. There are many such questions.

Comment: For pattern removal, see "Disable Pattern Lock via ADB" in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35848/16575). For remote control, follow the link @GokulNC gave.

Answer (score 0):

If USB debugging was enabled before you broke the screen, you could install Vysor in your PC. You would also need to setup ADB in your PC. Once you start Vysor and connect your phone, it will automatically push the android app for Vysor into your phone and display your screen.

Comment: Vysor is Paid version and not displayed on screen.